# browsers receive different (php output) content from same web

Tags: php, apache, browser, cross-browser

I don't know how to even explain this (just see the title...), but one browser is receiving different php output than the other.

I have the following html/php code:

```
<p><?= $lang->getW('t1_title') ?></p>
```

That is supposed to print some text. In firefox, I can see that text perfectly (and confirmed over irc that ie and edge too). But browsers like Chromium (and chrome) and Opera are not displaying the text, instead they're displaying the code between quotes:

```
<p>t1_title</p>
```

Just in case it has something to do with the server side: the function tries to get the text from memcached or from the database (saving it in memcached for the next time), so in the end it returns the string that corresponds to that id (`t1_title` in this case)

The function code is:

```
public function getW($word, $array = NULL) {
    $sql = TRUE;

    if ($this->cacheAvailable) {
        $text = $this->memCached->get("en_$word");

        if ( FALSE !== $text ) {
            $sql = FALSE;
            $word = $text;
        }
    }

    if ( TRUE === $sql ) {
        $mysqli = $this->aet->getAetSql();

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM locales_en WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1')) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $word);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            $word = FALSE;

            if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $text);
                $stmt->fetch();

                $text = nl2br($text);
                $this->memCached->set("en_$word", $text);
                $word = $text;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( NULL !== $array && FALSE !== $word ) {
        $word = $this->getVar($word, $array);
    }

    return $word;
}
```

Edit: The solution is to never forget to use debug code like:

```
echo $mysqli->error;
```

for development.

But I just noticed that I only uploaded 1 locale table and not the rest (locales_es, locales_fr, etc...). So that's what the error message would have been: table locales_xx does not exists.

Comment: show your code from getW plz

Comment: added the function code.

Comment: You could (temporarily) echo debug information or append it to $word  to see where getW is failing when the browser is chrome / chromium.

Comment: I'm using `var_dump()` but no luck yet. Where would you suggest that I put it?

Comment: Ok, found the problem... some browsers have english locale, others spanish and I uploaded only 1 locale table so that's why, there's only 1 locale table, so the function prints just that cuz there's no table to get from... Also my fault again for not using `echo $mysqli->error;` for development :P